# How calculate columns in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview and a column with the text box in the header of a text box. The box header text I have to put any amount and when I got in the textbox gridview other amount that they have both multiplied and then divided by 100. I know I have to use jQuery, but I can not find a solution for this. Can someone help me please. thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the minimum required code to reproduce this issue? And share what you have tried that did not work.

Comment: Hi well im trying multiplicate the ammount in the header with the amount in the textbox from the gridview and in the next column show me the result from this operation

Comment: Ok, but you still need to share what you have done so far. This will provide a great deal of context.

Comment: i have this in my html

Comment: i cant paste my code and i have low points to up a picture

Comment: ok now check the image i need to put an amount in the textbox "Numero Documento" and in the column from the gridview "Porcentaje" any amount and both amount have to multiplicate and show the result in "Cantidad"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your html do something like this im taking your columns to this example

> ```
>                                      <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
>                                              Width="800px" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" 
>                                             Height="1px" PageSize="8" 
>                                             GridLines="Vertical" AllowSorting="True" 
>                                             BorderStyle="Solid">
>                                         <Columns>
>                                             <asp:BoundField DataField="ccc1" HeaderText="ccc1" />
>                                             <asp:BoundField DataField="ccc2" HeaderText="ccc2" />
>                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ccc3">
>                                             <ItemTemplate>
>                                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
>                                             </ItemTemplate>
>                                             </asp:TemplateField>
>                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Result">
>                                             <ItemTemplate>
>                                                 <asp:Label ID="txtResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
>                                             </ItemTemplate>
>                                             </asp:TemplateField>
>                                         </Columns>
>                                     </asp:GridView>
> ```

and with a jquery function do this

> function pageLoad() {

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#<%=GridView.ClientID%> [id*='txtValue']").change(function () {

            var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
            var value = document.getElementById("<%=textbox1.Clientid%>").value;

            $("td:eq(3) span", tr).html($(this).val() * value);

        });

    });
}
```

for this work you need add to your project jquery-1.7.2.min.js